Visual Studio 2019 How do you create a Custom App Wizard with a query page?
I'm working with this link at Microsoft how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates
The first step/section I'm successful. I can create a Solution with two Projects, it builds and I see my new custom template.
Now I'm stumped at the "Create a Custom Template Wizard".
Now I want to follow the instructions for the Wizards and I'm stumped at #1


Setup the VISIX project to allow it to create an assembly.


Then it goes to step #2

In Solution Explorer, select the VSIX project node. Below Solution
Explorer, you should see the Properties window. If you do not, select
View > Properties Window, or press F4. In the Properties window,
select the following fields to true:
Include Assembly in VSIX Container

Include Debug Symbols in Local VSIX Deployment

Include Debug Symbols in VSIX Container


I'm stumped at step1... I'm not a C# developer.  How much C# must I master to be able to create a C++ Custom Template Wizard?  The details for Step#1 are a mystery to me.
I will be looking at other Stack Overflow questions to see if I can find a trail of breadcrumbs.  But most prior answers are for VS2010-2015 versions.

I haven't built a custom template for a good number of years, but this old blog entry might be useful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsx/creating-a-vsix-deployable-c-project-template Note the "wizard" is C#, but the project it generates is C++. Some of the content is a bit dated, as VS is now 64 bit and installs into a different path. But the principles should all still be the same.
